# Blackjack python script, flow error when restarting game

Tags: python, blackjack

I am a Python newbie but I tried my hand at writing a blackjack script. After debugging and correcting all the obvious errors, I am coming across a strange incident that I can't figure out.

When the `total` is >21, it seems to skip past the `while (total < 21) and (stand != True):` block of code, even though at the beginning of the game loop I zero out all of the relevant variables.

I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out, and I can't help but think this has an obvious solution.

I don't understand why `while (total < 21) and (stand != True):` seems to be skipped even though it should be a true statement at the beginning of every game.

Here is the full code below. Feel free to test it yourselves to see what I mean.

```
import pygame
import random

print("Welcome to PyBlackjack V1.0")
done =  False

while not done:

    # --- Reset our Hands ---

    dealerhand = 0
    split = False
    stand = False
    total = 0

    # --- Dealing the Player's hand. ---

    print("Dealer is dealing hand.")
    firstcard = random.randrange(1, 15)
    print("First card:",str(firstcard),)
    secondcard = random.randrange(1, 15)
    print("Second card:",str(secondcard),)

    total = (firstcard + secondcard)

    print("Hand:",str(total),)

        # --- Bust Check ---

    if total > 21:
        print("Bust! Game Over.")
        newgame = input("Play again? Y/N: ")
        if str(newgame) == "n":
            done = True
            break
        else:
            print("Starting new game! Good Luck!")

    dealerfirstcard = random.randrange(1, 15)
    dealerholecard = random.randrange(1, 15)

    dealerhand = (dealerfirstcard + dealerholecard)

    print("Dealer's Hand:",str(dealerfirstcard))

    # --- Player decides what to do ---

    while (total < 21) and (stand != True):

        if split != True:
            print("Hand:",str(total))
        elif split == True:
            print("Left hand:",str(lefthand),"| Right hand:",str(righthand))

        playerchoice = input("Hit (1), Double Down(2), Split(3), Stand(4)?")

        if int(playerchoice) == 1:
            total += random.randrange(1, 15)
        elif int(playerchoice) == 2:
            #Reserved
            break
        elif int(playerchoice) == 3:
            if ((firstcard + secondcard) / 2) == firstcard and split != True:
                lefthand = (firstcard + random.randrange(1, 15))
                righthand = (secondcard + random.randrange(1, 15))
                split = True
            else:
                print("You cannot split this hand!")
        elif int(playerchoice) == 4:
            print("You stand.")
            stand = True
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice!")

    print("Hand:",total,)

    if total > 21:
        print("Bust! Game Over.")

    newgame = input("Play again? Y/N: ")
    if str(newgame) == "n":
        done = True
        break
    else:
        print("Starting new game! Good Luck!")

    print("Dealer reveals hole card...")
    print("Dealer Hand:",str(dealerhand),)

    # --- Dealer hits until >= 17 ---

    while dealerhand < 17:
        print("Dealer hits...")
        dealerhand = (dealerhand + random.randrange(1, 15))
        print("Dealer hand:",dealerhand,)

    # --- Deciding who wins ---

    if dealerhand > 21:
        print("Dealer busts! You win!")
    elif dealerhand >= 17:
        print("Your hand:",total,"| Dealer hand:",dealerhand,)
        if split != True:
            if dealerhand >= total:
                print("You lose!")
            elif dealerhand < total:
                print("You win!")
        elif split == True:
            if lefthand > dealerhand:
                print("Left hand wins!")
            elif lefthand < dealerhand:
                print("Left hand loses!")
            else:
                print("An error occured. Ending program.")
                done = True
                break

            if righthand > dealerhand:
                print("Right hand wins!")
            elif righthand < dealerhand:
                print("Right hand loses!")
            else:
                print("An error occured. Ending program.")
                done = True
                break

    # --- To loop or not to loop ---

    newgame = input("Play again? Y/N: ")
    if str(newgame) == "n":
        done = True
        break
    else:
        print("Starting new game! Good Luck!")
```

Comment: Before even testing: "stand != True" should be "stand is not True" or "stand is False".  Don't check equality with True or False.  Use "is True" or "is False"

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If Total > 21, then it shouldn't enter a while loop whose conditional is Total < 21 and <something>.  Your biggest problem here is organization.  You're trying to do this as a purely procedural system (step by step, writing every step as a loop, conditional, input, output).  If you were to break the "parts" of blackjack into functions then procedurally call those functions, you'd be able see what's going on a each step more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is (sort of) working code. It still implements an odd variant of Blackjack (ranks go from 1 to 15, no such thing as an ace that counts as either 1 or 11, split is allowed after hitting). Splitting in general is not well handled here... I think you can split and then still hit/etc.? But hitting doesn't update either of the split hands, and splitting again doesn't do anything. I'll leave it to you to sort out those logical errors.

I think the issue you're describing is explained best by @Martin's answer. I ended up just simplifying this logic with an `else` to handle the non-bust case. Incidentally, there's no need to use flags like `stand` or `done` to exit a loop if what you really want is to just `break`.

I also cleaned up some miscellaneous things... dropped some unnecessary conversions to `str`, cleaned up the logic of detecting a player bust, detecting and printed pushes, etc. See the full code below and pay attention to the differences.

```
import random

print("Welcome to PyBlackjack V1.0")

while True:
    # --- Reset our Hands ---
    dealerhand = 0
    split = False
    total = 0

    # --- Dealing the Player's hand. ---
    print("Dealer is dealing hand.")
    firstcard = random.randrange(1, 15)
    print("First card:", firstcard)
    secondcard = random.randrange(1, 15)
    print("Second card:", secondcard)

    total = firstcard + secondcard

    print("Hand:", total)

    dealerfirstcard = random.randrange(1, 15)
    dealerholecard = random.randrange(1, 15)

    dealerhand = dealerfirstcard + dealerholecard

    print("Dealer's hole card:", dealerfirstcard)

    # --- Player decides what to do ---
    while total < 21:
        if not split:
            print("Hand:", total)
        else:
            print("Left hand:", lefthand, "| Right hand:", righthand)

        playerchoice = int(input("Hit (1), Double Down(2), Split(3), Stand(4)? "))

        if playerchoice == 1:
            total += random.randrange(1, 15)
        elif playerchoice == 2:
            #Reserved
            break
        elif playerchoice == 3:
            # NOTE: This will allow splitting even after hitting
            if firstcard == secondcard and not split:
                lefthand = firstcard + random.randrange(1, 15)
                righthand = secondcard + random.randrange(1, 15)
                split = True
            else:
                print("You cannot split this hand!")
        elif playerchoice == 4:
            print("You stand.")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice!")

    print("Hand:", total)

    if total > 21:
        print("Bust! Game Over.")
    else:
        print("Dealer reveals hole card...")
        print("Dealer hand:", dealerhand)

        # --- Dealer hits until >= 17 ---
        while dealerhand < 17:
            print("Dealer hits...")
            dealerhand += random.randrange(1, 15)
            print("Dealer hand:", dealerhand)

        # --- Deciding who wins ---
        if dealerhand > 21:
            print("Dealer busts! You win!")
        else:
            print("Your hand:", total, "| Dealer hand:", dealerhand)
            if not split:
                if dealerhand >= total:
                    print("You lose!")
                elif dealerhand < total:
                    print("You win!")
                else:
                    print("Push.")
            else:
                if lefthand > dealerhand:
                    print("Left hand wins!")
                elif lefthand < dealerhand:
                    print("Left hand loses!")
                else:
                    print("Push.")

                if righthand > dealerhand:
                    print("Right hand wins!")
                elif righthand < dealerhand:
                    print("Right hand loses!")
                else:
                    print("Push.")

    # --- To loop or not to loop ---
    newgame = input("Play again? Y/N: ")
    if str(newgame) == "n":
        break
    else:
        print("Starting new game! Good Luck!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user busts and chooses to start a new game, your code doesn't start from the beginning of the `while not done` loop, it just keeps going forward. So when you arrive at the `while (total < 21) and (stand != True)` line, total is still total that lead the user to bust.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are playing the game inside the {while not done:} 
It only breaks out of it if the player types "n"
but the function to start a new game is later in the code than the variable assignments, which I believe, never gets re-initiated.
Also, it would help your coding if you break it smaller functions or methods.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. But I thought by simply setting the variables = 0 and resetting my booleans at the top of the loop would work.